# how to show data without property name

Tags: javascript, html-table

The problem that i am facing is that i want to render data on to the table and i don't want to render it by using property name because there is a lot of field 
Here is my code :

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
             var parse = JSON.parse(response)
             var temp = []
             var temprow = []
             // var tempcol = []
             var data = JSON.parse(parse.GridData)
             var temp2 = valuesToArray(data[0])
              var editdata = data
              console.log(editdata)
              for (var j =0; j < editdata.length; j++) {
              var tempObjectValues= Object.values(editdata[j])      
                  for(var i = 0; i < tempObjectValues.length ; i++ ){
                        Array.prototype.push.apply(temp, [tempObjectValues[i]]);
                  }
                  temprow.push(temp)
              }
              console.log(temprow,"row")
)}
```

My reeulst is getting duplicated if there is 2 rows in my current data then it will repeat the data on to the table you can see the result

This is the parse data that is in the json

```
{
BTU: "12",
Brand: "12as",
Color: "asd",
Coolant: "123",
CoolingPower: "213",
CountryOfMNF: "asd",
Current: "213",
EER: "123",
EnergyRating: "ASD",
HeatingPower: "213",
Id: "1",
InputPowerheating: "231",
InputpowerCooling: "31",
IsInverter: "12",
IsVerified: "1",
MarketPrice: "21",
MaximumPower: "123",
Model: "asd",
OEMURL: "321",
RatedPower: "213",
Reviews: "ASD",
SEER: "213",
Sales_URL: "123",
Series: "sa",
Size: "1",
TypeID: "1",
YearOfMNF: "11121",
}
```

This is just a first index array data from my array
I want this array as all property value without propertyname on another array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New**
Updated my answer. Try like below

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    var parse = JSON.parse(response);
    var temp = [];
    var temprow = [];
    // var tempcol = [];
    var data = JSON.parse(parse.GridData);
    var temp2 = valuesToArray(data[0]);
    var editdata = data;
    temprow = editdata.map(function(i) { return Object.values(i); });       
    console.log(temprow,"row")
)}
```

**Old**

You need to initialize `temp = []` inside beginning of first for loop. Try as below:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    var parse = JSON.parse(response);
    var temp = [];
    var temprow = [];
    // var tempcol = [];
    var data = JSON.parse(parse.GridData);
    var temp2 = valuesToArray(data[0]);
    var editdata = data;
    for (var j =0; j < editdata.length; j++) {
        var tempObjectValues= Object.values(editdata[j])
        temp = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < tempObjectValues.length ; i++ ){
            Array.prototype.push.apply(temp, [tempObjectValues[i]]);
        }
        temprow.push(temp)
    }
    console.log(temprow,"row")
)}
```